# R plot x and y axes changes

Tags: r, plot

I have my data:

```r
x <- list(10,50,100,250,500,2500)
y <- list(0.09090909,0.01960784,0.003984064,0.003984064,0.001996008,0.0003998401)
```

I want to link my data to  code found on this website

```r
log_c <- seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(log_c = log_c, response = V(log_c, E, HS, log_EC50))

ggplot(df, aes(log_c, response)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I want to put the x data in place of log_c and y data in place of response. These are my beginnings in R, so I am asking for help

Comment: Hi @D_W! Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help you, it would be better if you provide an example of the plot to want to "replicate".

Comment: I tried but I have too few points to add a photo

Comment: or if you mean function V <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50))) and values HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)
E <- 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same logic as @Ben Bolker: Just another way:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x,y) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

At a minimum this will work:

1. you have expressed your x and y values as lists; it will work better if they are (atomic) *vectors* (which you would have gotten using `c()` instead of `list()`). Put them into a data frame (not strictly necessary, but best practice):

```r
df <- data.frame(x=unlist(x), y = unlist(y))
```

2. Use the data frame to draw your plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
```

To get your graph looking a little more like the example in your post,

```r
scalefun <- function(y) (y-min(y))/diff(range(y))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y = scalefun(y))) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have one more question to do my graph more precisely, to do the normalization I want to set the highest value of y as Ymax and the smallest as YO and use the formula 1> y - Y0 / Ymax-Y0> Y0 it is possible Ben Bolker?