# plot using curve()

Tags: r, curve

I want to plot a curve with C values on the X axis and V_C values on the Y axis. I also want my curve to be normalised to V_max. I also want the means to be visible as dots on the curve.

I’ve tried this:

```
V_max=15
H=1
n=1
C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)


fun <- function( C, H, n ){
  2 / (3 + (C / H)^n) 
}

mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(C)){
V_C <- V_max*fun(C[i],H,n)
x3 <- rnorm(1000,V_C,1)
mylist[i] <- mean(x3)
}

curve(fun, -10, 10, col ="red", ylab ="V_C")
```

My output curve should be similar to this picture:
[image]

Comment: This question is very similar to the one asked by other users [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432370/r-plot-x-and-y-axes-changes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74441812/r-calculating-the-mean-in-a-for-loop). Have you created multiple accounts?  [That's allowed as long as you aren't using the accounts to vote for each other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will) (or other nefarious purposes) but seems weird ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function's graph doesn't match the posted plot. I have defined an auxiliary function `f` to normalize to `V_max`.

The function's form shows it's graph is a hyperbole, so it has a vertical asymptote. The asymptote is the zero of its denominator and can be found with `uniroot`.

```r
V_max=15
H=1
n=1
C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)

fun <- function( C, H, n ){
  2 / (3 + (C / H)^n) 
}

# to normalize to V_max
f <- function(C, H, n, V_max) V_max*fun(C, H, n)

set.seed(2022)
my_means <- sapply(C, \(x) {
  V_C <- V_max * fun(x, H, n)
  x3 <- rnorm(1000,V_C,1)
  mean(x3)
})
my_means
#> [1] 10.001372  9.963173  9.670872  7.489163

# find asymptote
asym <- uniroot(\(C) 3 + (C / H), c(-10, 10))
asym$root
#> [1] -3

curve(f(x, H, n, V_max), -10, 10, col ="red", ylab ="V_C")
points(C, my_means, col = "black", pch = 16)
# asymptote
abline(v = asym$root, lty = 'dashed')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To plot just the branch above the asymptote, use the value found with `uniroot` as x axis left end point.

```r
curve(f(x, H, n, V_max), asym$root, 10, col ="red", ylab ="V_C")
points(C, my_means, col = "black", pch = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Tanks for your answer.Could you please show me what should I do in my curve code to it resembles what is shown in the picture? I am really new in R

Comment: Can I use for example curve shape (fun, from=0, to=2500, n=101) in code you give me Rui Barradas? Sorry if it is trivial question I am new in R. Please respond

Comment: @daisydomnie You can use 0 and 2500 as limits if you want but it will not give you the shape in the question's plot. Your function has a vertical asymptote at `C == -3*H`, its graph is a hyperbole.

Comment: Thank you again. So if I understand correctly I have to remove the asymptote at x == 0 that my graph resembled the one in the picture?

Comment: @daisydomnie Yes, to have only one branch of the hyperbole you will plot from `-3*H` to a value greater than that one. (It's not `x == 0`, my mistake). Will edit.

Comment: Thank you very much once more

Comment: @daisydomnie See if it is more clear after the edit.

Comment: So, if I understand the function of the curve well, I can give it my function fun  and 4 means  as points through which the curve is to pass through it to work?

Comment: @daisydomnie The function `f` is a function meant to simplify the call to `curve`. Its only real computation is to scale to `V_max`. It calls `fun` as you wrote it and multiplies the return value by `V_max`. That's it.